# Python code to fetch file count from remote server

Tags: python, linux

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5

import subprocess

import os

command=r'ssh <some-server> "(echo \"import os\" ; echo \"for r,d,f in os.walk('/etc/'): print (r,len(f))\")| python"'

ssh=subprocess.call(["bash","-c","{0}".format("command")])
print(ssh)
```

I'm trying to run the above code and the code gives the following error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./test_filelist.py", line
>   11, in 
>       command=r'ssh  "(echo \"import os\" ; echo \"for r,d,f in os.walk('/etc/'): print (r,len(f))\")| python"' NameError: name 'etc'
>   is not defined

How do I fix that , Is there something that I need to escape . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not escaping correctly your `os.walk('/etc/')`

Try with:

```
os.walk(\"/etc/\")
```

Comment: The error is gone now , but for some reason the code seems to be giving no o/p .